# Why is Territory management not available?

Tags: administration, territory-management

My org doesn`t have Territory Settings in setup. What is reason? Profile - System administrator, Organization Edition - Enterprise Edition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Territory management](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=territories_enable.htm&type=5) is not enabled by default in Salesforce. To request territory management for your organization, contact salesforce.com. If you have already done this step and you are seeing this feature missing recently. The following might be the cause

Migrating to the new Collaborative Forecasting requires disabling Territory Management 1.0

As per this [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334120&type=1&mode=1), the Customizable Forecasting was retired for all customers as of Summer ’20. Users can’t access the Customizable Forecasting feature and its underlying data. Salesforce encourages you to migrate to Collaborative Forecasts. The documentation also quotes "If you agree to the steps above, please contact support to enable permission to allow you to deactivate Customizable Forecasting and/or Territory Management 1.0"

I recommend engaging support if you have any specific questions

Comment: Your first link is broken

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to contact to Salesforce Support Team and request enabling Enterprise Territory Management

Comment: Yes you have to contact the support.

Answer (score 0):

The territory management feature is scheduled for retirement for all customers as of Summer ’21. After the feature is retired, users can’t access the original territory management feature and its underlying data. We encourage you to migrate to Enterprise Territory Management.

[Offical Document](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000318370&type=1&mode=1)

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, but my org haven't territory settings in setup. Solution is to contact Salesforce team